# Storing file on azure website but not opening php

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-app-service

Trying to upload image into root directory to access it from url.

```
    $url = "http://my.com/myimage.jpg";
    $dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/";
    var_dump($dir);
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    $fp = fopen($dir ."". basename($url), 'wb');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);
```

When i'm tring to access it on azure website its showing a blank page. 
No error was displayed

Comment: Do you have any update?

Comment: yuup, thanks it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Azure Web Apps are based on Windows VMs, the file system separator is `\`.

Please consider the following code snippet:

```
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
$url = "http://my.com/myimage.jpg";
$dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "\\";
echo file_get_contents($dir . basename($url));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script is correctly written. I have tried and works fine, but you need to set image headers

```
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
$url = 'http://my.com/myimage.jpg';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$result= curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch) ;
echo $result;
```